# How to apply brush color with dots in Paint android application?

Tags: android, paint

I am using following code to apply font color when user click on perticular color like RED.

```
mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color2));
```

And color2 in `color.xml` file is

```
<color name="color2">#FF3C00</color>
```

Now I am facing problem while applying following color.

[image: RED COLOR WITH WHITE DOTS]

I using canvas to draw paint on touching it in my application and i want to draw something like attached screen on canvas. I am able to draw it but It looks like solid color (I mean full circle but not dot dot inside)

Please help me to find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BitmapShader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html) for achieve that..

Here is sample code.. Try this code, I hope it will work..

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.shader);  
//Initialize the BitmapShader with the Bitmap object and set the texture tile mode  
BitmapShader mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);  

fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);  
//Assign the 'fillBMPshader' to this paint  
fillPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);  

//Draw the fill of any shape you want, using the paint object.
canvas.drawCircle(posX, posY, 100, fillPaint);
```

Comment: When i use this code,it only drawing one time and doesn't draw over previously drawn paint